# How to remove old-style C macros in this C++ 14 piece of code, keeping efficiency and speed?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, constexpr

Take a look at the following piece of code, can you suggest me a simple way to substitute the two macros with modern C++ 14 constructs, say templates and/or constexpr expressions without losing efficiency and speed?

Thanks, Matteo

```
#include <iostream>

#define PACK_BUFF(ptrBuff, value) \
    *reinterpret_cast<decltype(value)*>(ptrBuff) = value; \
    ptrBuff += sizeof(value);

#define UNPACK_BUFF(ptrBuff, value) \
    value = *reinterpret_cast<decltype(value)*>(ptrBuff); \
    ptrBuff += sizeof(value);

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024];

    uint8_t value8 = 31;
    uint16_t value16 = 42;

    unsigned char* ptr = buffer;

    PACK_BUFF(ptr, value8);
    PACK_BUFF(ptr, value16);

    ptr = buffer;

    uint8_t outValue8;
    uint16_t outValue16;

    UNPACK_BUFF(ptr, outValue8);
    UNPACK_BUFF(ptr, outValue16);

    std::cout << unsigned(outValue8) << std::endl;
    std::cout << outValue16 << std::endl;

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `template <typename T> void pack(unsigned char*& ptr, T const& value) { std::memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof value); ptr += sizeof(T); }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I would like to avoid using memcpy, thus a function call...

Comment: The template can be inlined, and memcpy itself is almost certainly is inlined.  `template <typename T> void unpack(unsigned char*& ptr, T& value) { std::memcpy(&value, ptr, sizeof value); ptr += sizeof(T); }`

Comment: @Pampo functions can be inlined. look at what a compiler emits for your existing code vs `memcpy`

Comment: If there is any chance that your memory reads or writes won't be to/form properly aligned memory locations, you pretty much have to use `memcpy()` or you'll invoke undefined behavior.  Don't worry, `memcpy()` calls are as efficient as they can be, compilers explicitly know about that function and how to handle it.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me, but just for learning, how could I achieve the same result using reinterpret_cast instead?

Comment: The only way to use it with defined/implementation defined behavior is to use C++20 `std::bit_cast`. Before that, `just reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you are not right in general case. There is no guarantee that `memcpy` will be elided, and it does not get to in many cases.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `reinterpret_cast` (which leads to undefined behavior)?

Comment: @interjay a) it only does lead to UB if original object in the buffer is not of a proper type b) because it guarantees that there will be no copy.

Comment: @SergeyA What is a "proper type"? This is a violation of the strict aliasing rule for any type except `char`, and therefore UB. And I have no idea what you're talking about regarding "no copy", there's certainly a copy (the whole point of the macro is to copy data).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` cast in this case will result in **undefined behavior**, because using `reinterpret_cast` relies on the programmer being meticulously correct about the cast actually being to the correct type.  Which is not the case here.  If you only allow packing and unpacking of `unsigned char` (also okay for `char` or `signed char`, because of allowed aliasing of those types) then it would be okay.

Comment: @SergeyA my feeling is that if the compiler doesn't elide the call to `memcpy()`, it's probably because eliding the call to `memcpy()` isn't possible in that case without causing a problem.  A program that 'runs faster' but invokes undefined behavior isn't a useful result, and its common for the compiler to correctly handle edge cases that a human programmer might overlook.

Comment: @interjay no, you are wrong. If original object was of a type `int` (for example, directly created in the buffer via placement `new`) it is 100% defined. Although I missed the fact the OP is still copying, i thought it only aliases to correct type.

Comment: @SergeyA • placement `new` crashes on my machine when the `int` is not properly aligned.  The `reinterpret_cast` as per the OP's original code crashes for the same reason.

Comment: @SergeyA there's no placement new in the example usage

Comment: @Caleth I assume original main is for illustration only.

Comment: I'm already using reinterpret_cast without any problem, but I would like to perform both operations (casting and pointer move) in only one line of code, that's the reason for macro use.

Comment: @Eljay this is your particular architecture. For a lot of other architectures, such aliasing is integral part of application.

Comment: @SergeyA It is 100% undefined, look up the strict aliasing rule. Pretty much everything you have written here is wrong.

Comment: @SergeyA • it's **undefined behavior** for the C++ abstract machine.

Comment: @interjay I admit, it is undefined in a given complete code. `unpack_buffer` by itself is not undefined.

Comment: In the original code value is actually one of many class members that need to be transmitted over a network and the reconstructed (marshalled/unmarshalled) at the moment everything works fine.

Comment: @SergeyA By itself it's just a macro definition so obviously doesn't cause UB. It becomes UB when you use it to access an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Pampo everything works fine *now*, but may break when you change to a different compiler version or compilation flags.

Comment: @Pampo if you are using copy (as you are at the moment) you should replace with `memcpy`, since it would be the same thing, but more conforming. However, if you entity-serialize your objects, you can avoid copying them, and instead alias the whole object in the buffer received. This will be undefined pre-C++20 bit_cast, but it would work correctly on many modern architectures, including x86_64.

Comment: @interjay Like I said before, **only** if the pointer does not contain the object of the right type.

Comment: @SergeyA So apparently only you understand how the strict aliasing rule works, while everyone else that posted here is wrong. In reality, the standard is clear that aliasing between incompatible types is not allowed, with an exception given to accessing something as `char` (which is not what happens here - accessing a `char` array as another type).

Comment: I'm sad for this conversation, of course it was not my intention... Anyway, I understand all your doubts on reinterpret_cast usage, ok, it's architecture/compiler dependant and so on, but please try to forget about this now, may we just put the two cited lines of code inside one template function or anything like that (not macro of course) without using C++20?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything C++14 here, just C++98

```
template<typename T>
void pack_buff(unsigned char *& ptr, T & value) {
    std::memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof(T));
    ptr += sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T>
void unpack_buff(unsigned char *& ptr, T & value) {
    std::memcpy(&value, ptr, sizeof(T));
    ptr += sizeof(T);
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not the same. There a lot of cases where you will end up doing a copy.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this code is part of a project using C++ 14.

Comment: Sorry @SergeyA, I was answering while you wrote, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @SergeyA edited to no copying version. As a bonus will break in places where prvalues were being evaluated multiple times

Comment: @Pampo What I mean is there isn't anything that C++11 or C++14 added that you need here.

Comment: Why not use placement-new?

Comment: @Deduplicator because we have no idea if ptr is aligned properly or not

Comment: Ah, the original code was buggy. Skipped that. Would be nice to call that out though.

Comment: @Caleth this is only an issue w/ some architectures, and there is a bit_cast in C++20.

Comment: @SergeyA OP is moving to C++14

Comment: @Caleth and in C++14 a lot of systems are built on using this.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, on some systems this is the same as a `reinterpret_cast`, and on others the `reinterpret_cast` has undesired behaviour. I don't see the problem with moving to the correct everywhere version, that ends up as the same object code

Comment: @Caleth, when I typed my comment, I missed the fact that OP already has a copy in place. I am used to applications which do not copy in such aliasing scenarios, so I did't notice it is different. I admitted that in the other comment section, but not here.

Comment: As I explained, I'm using the same code based on reinterpret_cast on both sides of my network, then there are no unaligned pointers or things like that, may you please answer my original (and successive) questions, instead of focusing on other issues that are not present in my case? Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @Pampo the example usage you show has unaligned access to the `uint16_t`, because it's on an odd offset into `buffer`. The most insidious kind of undefined behaviour is "it works *right now*"

Comment: Thanks @Caleth, but as far as I understand, even if I use memcpy I could get unaligned access, my goal is to pack the values in a buffer without holes, of course.

Comment: @Pampo no, you can copy the value representation of the `uint16_t` into the buffer anywhere you like, so long as you copy it out into an `uint16_t` at the destination

Comment: Thanks @Caleth, but why things should be different using reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @Pampo because with `reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(ptr)`, you are lying about the existence of a `uint16_t` object where `ptr` points.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my own project I can safely assume to find what I expect, since I both write and subsequently read, but I agree that in a more general case it can be wrong.

Comment: @Pampo *so far* it hasn't been a problem in your project. An update in your compiler could suddenly break everything. That's the insidious problem with undefined behaviour